# Meaning of word “menu” in "briser menu l'os" from cooking book

Tags: sens, alimentation

The cooking book La Cuisine du Marche, by Bocuse, has the following sentence in its recipe for *Bœuf à la bourguignonne*:

> « Désosser, ébouillanter et ficeler le pied de veaux; briser menu l'os »

which I translate in English to:

> "debone, boil, and tie up in string the calf foot, then break [something about the bone]"

But I'm a bit confused by the word *menu* in the last clause. How is the word being used, and what's the translation in English?

Comment: Note that *briser menu* if more often used figuratively nowadays in the colloquial expression *les briser menu*, e.g. *Il commence à me les briser menu* : He starts to piss me off. (see [Lino Ventura - Les tontons flingueurs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bg_OL7OXVj8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Briser menu* means “briser très finement”.